# Remove characters in a string that does not match letters, numbers, specific symbols, and Chinese characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to remove a character in a string if it's not:

- Letters
- Numbers
- Space or Whitespace
- Specific symbols : ( ) . - /
- Chinese Characters

for example:

```
A3M \ Mfg. (&&$) *Co; 應龙龍.
```

becomes:

```
A3M Mfg. () Co 應龙龍.
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
$string = 'A3M \ Mfg. (&&$) *Co; 應龙龍.';
$string = preg_replace('/[^-A-Za-z0-9().\/ \u3040-\u30ff\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\uf900-\ufaff\uff66-\uff9f]/s', '', $string);

echo $string;
```

but the unwanted characters are still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP supports code points notation using `\x{....}` instead of `\u`. However there is a better way to handle this using [unicode character class `\p{Han}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to natch all Chinese characters.

Use this regex to search:

```sh
[^-\w()./\s\p{Han}]+
```

Replace with an empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wVj9sF/1)

**Code:**

```sh
$string = 'A3M \ Mfg. (&&$) *Co; 應龙龍.';
$string = preg_replace('~[^-\w()./\s\p{Han}]+~u', '', $string);
echo $string;
//=> "A3M  Mfg. () Co 應龙龍."
```

Note that it might leave few instances of double spaces due to presence of spaces around removable characters in your original string.